# Is there any way to see all the incoming transactions to a wallet address?

Tags: transactions, accounts, addresses, confirmations

I want to show block confirmations of the user's ether transaction to my account. How do I put watch on the incoming transactions?? I would need the transaction Id to know calculate block confirmations. But I can't view the incoming ether transaction for my account. Any way out?? Thanks.

Comment: This is very good question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using web3j/web3js, you can do it programmatically. I use web3j and I have this in my code:

```
web3j.transactionObservable().subscribe( tx -> {

        if( credentials.getAddress().equals( tx.getTo() )) {

            Logger.info( "This is my money! -> addr: {}, amt: {}", 
                    credentials.getAddress(), tx.getValue() );
        }
    });
```

Comment: This ignores incoming transactions sent as part of a smart contract function invocation.

Answer (score -2):

Go to https://etherscan.io put in the address you want to monitor.

"in" (green) indicates deposits.

"out" (orange) indicates withdrawals.

Comment: This is a centralized solution. Are there any decentralized solutions?